Exclude vscode c++ debugger header files
In GNU gdb (GDB) 14.1, i am wondering if it is possible to skip the bits/stdc++.h files in vscode's debugger.  I've tried even skipping a single file -exec skip file C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\include\\c++\\13.2.0\\bits\\stl_tree.h to no avail. I am wondering if anyone has tried this version, am I doing something wrong, or should I downgrade to an earlier version?
